# Local movie player is black and stuck as loading (Swift)

Tags: xcode, swift, video

I am trying to play a local movie in my app, but when I call my method to start playing the movie, the player appears but is always black and I have a loading message. Can someone help me understand this?

```
func startPlayingVideo() {

        let fileURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Sample", withExtension: "m4v")

        moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: fileURL)

        moviePlayer.prepareToPlay()

        /* Scale the movie player to fit the aspect ratio */
        moviePlayer.scalingMode = .AspectFit

        view.addSubview(moviePlayer.view)

        moviePlayer.setFullscreen(true, animated: false)

        /* Let's start playing the video in full screen mode */
        moviePlayer.play()
    }

    @IBAction func playVideo(sender: AnyObject) {
        //play movie
        startPlayingVideo()
    }
```

I'm not as experienced with coding with videos. Thanks in advance to the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be your `fileURL` become nil at runtime so try this following

In the Project Navigator select your project root > your Target > Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources. If your video is not listed in this list you should add it using the plus button

may be this will work.

Comment: Hi Dharmesh, you're absolutely right. That solved the problem. Thanks a lot for the help!